# Get price according distance

Tags: php

i am trying to create dynamic price calculation by distance.My requirment similar like this 
so I need a function where I can pass
distance and  then get price by distance

```
From 0 -10km = Rs10rs/km (fixed price)
10-15km = rs10Rs/km 
15 -20km = 9rs pre/km
20 -30km = 8.5rs per/km
25 -30km = 8rs per/km
30 -40km = 7.5rs per/km
30km -50km above = 7rs / km

foreach ($usersInfo as $index=> $users)
{
     $km= 0;
      $ridefrom=$users['ride_from'];
      $rideto=$users['ride_to'];//this is from lat long
      $tempLatLong = explode(',',$users['ride_from']);
      $tempLatLong1 = explode(',',$users['ride_to']);
      $key = array('lat','long');
      $to = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong); 
      $from = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong1);
      $km=distanceCalculation($from['lat'],$from['long'],$to['lat'],$to['long']).'km';
      $usersInfo[$index]['distance'] =$km;
      $carprice=10;// price will be change dynamical from back end admin can change this.

      if($carprice){
      $price=$km*10;
      }
      else{
        $price=$km*9;  
      }
      $usersInfo[$index]['price'] =$price;


                    return $usersInfo;
    }
```

Comment: You have ambiguities in your km ranges. What would be per km charge applied if I ride 26 km? 9rs or 8rs?.

Comment: prit.patel @ yes it is. but it  will be different

Comment: what is this `$carprice` and `$Bikeprice`.

Comment: What do you mean it would be different?

Comment: Nitin P @if i travel from bike then bike price will be different and if I travel from car then car price will be different

Comment: prit.patel@if you travel 26 km then price will be charged 8.5rs per km

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the category 25 to 30 km

Comment: prit.patel @ sorry I do not  i know  what you  trying to  ask?

Comment: prit.pate@can  you let me know how can  i calculate price simply

Comment: Can you properly describe how your price decreases according to distance? `basePrice - (.5rs * 5km)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function price_per_km($distance, $mode) {
  if ($mode == 'car') {
    switch (true) {
      case $distance <= 10:
        return 10*$distance;
      case $distance <= 15:
        return 10*$distance;
      case $distance <= 20:
        return 9*$distance;
      case $distance <= 25:
        return 8.5*$distance;
      case $distance <= 30:
        return 8*$distance;
      case $distance <= 40:
        return 7.5*$distance;
      default:
        return 7*$distance;
    }
  }
  else {
    // bike
    switch (true) {
      case $distance <= 10:
        return 12*$distance;
      case $distance <= 15:
        return 11*$distance;
      case $distance <= 20:
        return 10*$distance;
      case $distance <= 25:
        return 9*$distance;
      default:
        return 8*$distance;
    }
  }
}

echo price_per_km(5, 'car') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(12, 'car') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(25, 'car') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(35, 'car') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(5, 'bike') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(15, 'bike') . "\n";
echo price_per_km(35, 'bike') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
50
120
212.5
227.5
60
165
270
```

Comment: OP asks for `dynamic price calculation` This one is static

Comment: Nick@can i pas variable like that echo price_per_km($km, '$car') .

Comment: @Justinas my interpretation is that OP wants "dynamic" pricing in the meaning that it changes dependent on distance and mode of transport. If that is wrong I will happily delete post.

Comment: @newdeveloper Yes you can pass a variable, the way I have written the code assumes the value is either 'car' or something else but you could rewrite it to suit your needs. Anyway you can use something like `$mode = 'car'; echo price_per_km($km, $mode);`

Comment: Nick@ if I am passing this then return switch value        "price": 12

Comment: $km$ trying to calculate distance to pass $km. because $km hold the  distance value dynamicaly

Comment: @newdeveloper I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Nick @ dynamic distance coming from this section    $km=distanceCalculation($from['lat'],$from['long'],$to['lat'],$to['long']).'km'; so I am trying to pass $km value  in this price_per_km()

Comment: That should be fine what I didn't understand was your comment about returning switch value price 12?

Comment: nic@   $ridelooking=$users['ride_looking_for'];//its containing car and bike category
      $price=price_per_km($km, $ridelooking); //$km, hold the dynamic distnace

Comment: Note that you shouldn't add the '.km' to $km until you display it otherwise it could cause problems trying to use the value as a number.

Comment: That code should work if `$ridelooking` is either 'car' or something else.

Comment: $ridelooking@but  its  not working , condition fails when pass $km and  $ridelooking in price_per_km

Comment: nick@ why this return 12;

Comment: What are the values of $ridelooking and $km and what is the error?

Comment: If it returns 12 then that means $distance<10 and $mode != 'car'

Comment: Nick @well little bit correction . we need price by distance we do not need return  distance,,  change you answere       return 12*$distance; like this i will vote you up. Thanks man

Comment: Hi I have edited code hopefully that does what you want?